# Android Sqlite Data lost when Application Hangs/Freeze and restarted

Tags: android, sqlite, data-loss

Recently my users are complaining that application hangs while using it and the data stored getting lost when the reboot the mobile.

Its not happening everytime too.

Can some one please tell me for what are all the reasons sqlite data will get lost.?

Also for what are the reasons android application freeze?

Background : My application perform sqlite operation from all the screens. The device

> Model Number: Samsung GT-18160 , Android Version:2.3.6 , Kernel
>   Version:2.6.35.7-1219296 dpi@DELL210#2

Comment: `SQlite` or `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 0):

You can assume no data should be lost. But you may want to nail down crash culprit first - luckily your user is on 2.x so tell him to use tools like `aLogCat` and grab the logs after your app crash. Then check what's there and fix. That should solve your "data lost" issue as whatever it is, it occurs after your app crashed. If it stop crashing then it should not trigger the snowball....

Comment: makes sense, but actually log collector application is installed on the device, but when the application hangs, users could't able to do anything, all the keys are hanged. So user restarting mobile and logs wipes out.

Comment: yes. exactly. Menu,Home,Back nothing responding. Users removed battery to restart the mobile.